How do I have two arrows going out of node downwards on different horizontal coordinates?
I have tikz code (at the bottom of my question) that produces the following flow chart in the picture (on the left). I do not like how arrows '1' and '2' coincide when going out. I tried the solution of this answer by rewriting \draw [arrow] (ring_w_unit)--(skew_field); to \draw [arrow] ([xshift=-1cm]ring_w_unit)--([xshift=-1cm]skew_field);. This does not give the desired result where the arrow is straight down (vertical) instead of slanted.
My question is: how do I make lines 1 and 2 not coincide while having line 1 vertical (not slanted).

Start of code:
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  block_set/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
  block_ring/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
  block_module/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
  mytext/.style={align=left, text width=6cm, midway, right},
  mytext_left/.style={align=right, text width=6cm, midway, left},
  line/.style={thick}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

% nodes
\node (set_R) [block_ring] {Set $R$};
\node (ring) [block_ring, below=2cm of set_R] {Ring $(R,+,\cdot)$};
\node (ring_w_unit) [block_ring, below left= 1cm and -1cm of ring] {Ring with Unit};
\node (commutative_ring) [block_ring, below right= 1cm and -1cm of ring] {Commutative Ring};
\node (ghost_to_field) [below= 0.7cm of commutative_ring, draw, shape=circle, thick]{$+$};
\node [below= 2cm of ring, align=center]{$\exists$ multiplicative\\ inverse $\forall r\in R$};
\node (field) [block_ring, below = 0.3cm of ghost_to_field] {Field};
\node (skew_field) [block_ring] at (ring_w_unit|-field) {Skew Field};

% arrows
\draw [arrow] (set_R) -- (ring) node[mytext]{
    BC `addition' $+$ $=$ \textit{abelian group}\\
    BC `multiplication' $\cdot$ $=$ \textit{monoid}\\
    $\exists$ additive unit $\forall r\in R$ called \textit{zero} denoted $0$
};
\draw [arrow] (ring)-|(ring_w_unit) node[mytext_left]{$\exists$ multiplicative unit $\forall r\in R$ called \textit{one} or \textit{identity} denoted $1$};
\draw [arrow] (ring)-|(commutative_ring) node[mytext]{multiplication is \textit{commutative}};
\draw [arrow] (ring_w_unit)--(skew_field);
\draw [arrow] (ring_w_unit) |- (ghost_to_field);
\draw [arrow] (commutative_ring) -- (ghost_to_field);
\draw [arrow] (ghost_to_field) -- (field);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


A response is on its way to you :)

You forgot to specify the anchor. If no anchor is provided, TikZ will draw the line from the center of the node. The .south anchor ensures that the drawing's starting point is relative to the bottom edge of the node.
\draw [arrow] ([xshift = -5pt]ring-w-unit.south) -- ([xshift = -5pt]skew-field.north);



Full code
I took the initiative to refactor the code to make it clearer and more explicit. Hope you don't mind :)
\documentclass[tikz, border={-1.5cm 0.1cm -1.5cm 0.1cm}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    % my blocks
    block/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
    block/ring/.style = {block, fill=blue!30},
    % block/set/.style = {block, fill=red!30},% not used (?)
    % block/module/.style = {block, fill=green!30},% not used (?)
    % my text
    mytext/.style = {text width=6cm, midway},
    mytext/left/.style = {mytext, align=right, left = 2pt},
    mytext/right/.style = {mytext, align=left, right = 2pt},
    % my arrows
    line/.style = {thick},
    arrow/.style = {line, ->, >=stealth},
    circle/.style = {draw, shape=circle, thick},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (set-R) [block/ring] {Set \(R\)};
    \node (ring) [block/ring, below = 2cm of set-R] {Ring \((R, + ,\cdot)\)};
    \node (ring-w-unit) [block/ring, below left = 1cm and -.5cm of ring] {Ring with Unit};
    \node (commutative-ring) [block/ring, below right = 1cm and -.5cm of ring] {Commutative Ring};
    \node (ghost-to-field) [circle, below = 1cm of commutative-ring]{\(+\)};
    \node (field) [block/ring, below = 0.7cm of ghost-to-field] {Field};
    \node (skew-field) [block/ring] at (ring-w-unit |- field) {Skew Field};
    
    \draw [arrow] (set-R) -- (ring) node[mytext/right]{
        BC ``addition'' \(+=\) \emph{abelian group}\\
        BC ``multiplication'' \(\cdot=\) \emph{monoid}\\
        \(\exists\) additive unit \(\forall r\in R\) called \emph{zero}\\denoted \(0\)
    };
    \draw [arrow] (ring) -| (ring-w-unit)
        node[mytext/left, yshift = -.5cm]{\hfill\(\exists\) multiplicative unit \(\forall r\in R\)\\called \emph{one} or \emph{identity}\\denoted \(1\)};
    \draw [arrow] (ring) -| (commutative-ring) node[mytext/right, yshift = -.5cm]{multiplication is\\\emph{commutative}};
    \draw [arrow] ([xshift = -5pt]ring-w-unit.south) -- ([xshift = -5pt]skew-field.north);
    \draw [arrow] ([xshift = +5pt]ring-w-unit.south) |- (ghost-to-field)
        node [text width = 2.5cm, above = 2pt, xshift = -2.5cm]{\(\exists\) multiplicative\\inverse \(\forall r\in R\)};
    \draw [arrow] (commutative-ring) -- (ghost-to-field);
    \draw [arrow] (ghost-to-field) -- (field);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you!
Happy to see the code refactored in a more efficient way. I see you made some changes to the text, node names and styles: I specifically like the styles (block_set and block_module indeed is not used: an oversight from me when I cut this minimal working model out from the larger piece of code).
Did you change anything else besides the node names, styling and the text?

I'm glad you appreciated it! I did increase the spacing between the nodes and reassigned the ∃ multiplicative inverse text to the "sum" node instead of "ring" to better align with the logical flow and structure.

A small variation of nice @Emanuele Nardi answer (+1) with renamed nodes names(for shorter code) and reorganizes order of node placement and connection drawing:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 7mm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth},
     N/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!30,
                 minimum width=33mm, minimum height=7mm, align=center},
     Q/.style = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, align=#1},
   sum/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, font=\Large,
                 node contents={$+$}},
                        ]
\node (n1)  [N] {Set \(R\)};
\node (n2)  [N, below = 17mm of n1]         {Ring \((R, + ,\cdot)\)};

\node (n3R) [N, below right = of n2.south]  {Commutative Ring};
\node (n4R) [sum, below = 7mm of n3R];
\node (n5R) [N, below = 7mm of n4R]         {Field};

\node (n3L) [N, below  left = of n2.south] {Ring with Unit};
\node (n4L) [N, at={(n3L  |-  n5R)}]        {Skew Field};

\draw[arr] (n1) -- (n2)     node[pos=0.50,right,Q=left]   
                    {BC ``addition'' \(+=\) \emph{abelian group}\\
                     BC ``multiplication'' \(\cdot=\) \emph{monoid}\\
                     \(\exists\) additive unit \(\forall r\in R\) called \emph{zero}\\denoted \(0\)}
            (n3L) edge (n4L)
            (n3R) edge (n4R)
            (n4R) -- (n5R);
\draw[arr] (n2) -| (n3R)    node[pos=0.75,right,Q=left]   
                    {\(\exists\) multiplicative unit \(\forall r\in R\)\\
                     called \emph{one} or \emph{identity}\\
                     denoted \(1\)};
\draw[arr]  (n2) -| (n3L)   node[pos=0.75,left,Q=right]    
                    {multiplication is\\
                     \emph{commutative}};
\draw[arr]  ([xshift = 3mm] n3L) |- (n4R)   node [pos=0.75,above,Q=center] 
                    {\(\exists\) multiplicative\\
                     inverse \(\forall r\in R\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


